# Redux dispatch inside Meteor.call or get Meteor.call value

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-redux

My project works with Meteor and `react-redux`

For redux to work, one must be able to access the dispatch function in the this.props of the component.

However when I use Meteor.call the callback's `this` property does not contain the redux function `dispatch` as is expected.

So this is my Meteor.call:

```
var testing;

Meteor.call('seed', mergedobj, function(err, seed){
      if(err){
        console.log('ERROR ERROR ERROR: when calling seed err', err);

        if(err.error === 'SWE_RISE_TRANS_NEGATIVE'){
        }
      }else{
        console.log('return of seed', seed)
        console.log('this', this)
        //this.props.dispatch(seedAction(seed))
        testing = seed

      }
    })
console.log('testing', testing) //'INITIAL' and not seed!!
```

I either need to change the `this` of the callback so I can call this.props.dispatch inside of the callback or I need to get the value of seed outside of the callback.....
How do I achieve this?
How do I get the value of seed inside variable that is outside of the callback's scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this syntax:

```
const dispatch = this.props.dispatch;
Meteor.call('seed', mergedobj, function(err, seed){
      if(err){
        // error handling here.
      }else{
        dispatch(seedAction(seed));
      }
})
```

So you don't have to deal with `this` keyword.